# Why floor division and normal division don't output same result in case of large integers

Tags: python-3.x, division, floor-division

my code is :

`a=99999999999999995
b=long(a/5)
c=a//5
print(b,c)`

output is :
2e+16 19999999999999999

why different answer and how to get the same answer (in python3)

Comment: It is due to the finite precision of floating point numbers [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: how we can fix it